# Merge Sort Visualisation JS

Tags: javascript, html, mergesort

```js
// variables
// arr has elements to be sorted
var arr = []
// temp is to store the intermediate results after merging
var temp = []
// seen is for marking visited i.e. sorted half as green
var seen = []
// length of array
var len = 50

// canvas initialisations
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
canvas.width = canvas.height = 1000
var canvaswidth = canvas.width
var canvasheight = canvas.height
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

// random array
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 500))
    temp.push(parseInt(0))
    seen.push(parseInt(0))
}

// initial contents of array to be sorted
// console.log(arr)

// draw the bars
draw = (s, e) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)

    // this loop will make unvisited bars in the upper half as black
    // and visited bars in the upper half as green
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500 - arr[i], 10, arr[i])
        if (seen[i]) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"
            ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500 - arr[i], 10, arr[i])
        }
    }

    // the part that was merged is made blue in the lower half
    // also its equivalent in the uper half is made white
    for (let i = s; i <= e; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff"
        ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500 - arr[i], 10, arr[i])
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0000ff"
        ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500, 10, arr[i])
        seen[i] = 1
    }

}

// merge
merge = (s, e) => {

    let m = parseInt((s + e) / 2)
    let p1 = s
    let p2 = m + 1
    let n1 = m
    let n2 = e
    let idx = s

    while (p1 <= n1 && p2 <= n2) {
        if (arr[p1] <= arr[p2]) {
            temp[idx++] = arr[p1++]
        }
        else {
            temp[idx++] = arr[p2++]
        }
    }

    while (p1 <= n1) {
        temp[idx++] = arr[p1++]
    }

    while (p2 <= n2) {
        temp[idx++] = arr[p2++]
    }

    idx = s
    while (idx <= e) {
        arr[idx] = temp[idx++]
    }

}

// delay
function mytimeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// mergesort
const mergesort = async (s, e) => {

    if (s < e) {
        let m = parseInt((s + e) / 2)
        await mergesort(s, m)
        await mergesort(m + 1, e)
        await merge(s, e)
        // await console.log(`merged ${s} to ${e} now draw...`)
        await draw(s, e)
        await mytimeout(500)
    }

}

// calls merge sort and at last 
// makes all bars become green in upper half
const performer = async () => {
    await mergesort(0, len - 1)
    // await console.log(arr)
    await draw()
}



performer()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
    <script src="testmerge.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now if i change the len variable in JS to above 50 i.e. 75 or 100 the code behaves oddly..why is it so?
Are there any optimisations possible??

Comment: Greetings, the downvote and vote to close comes from 1. not all code being right in the question 2. the admission that the code doesn't work at a certain point. Other than that, welcome to CodeReview ;)

Comment: @konijn perhaps you could help me now?

Comment: You have helped yourself by putting the code in this question which fixes the first part, however fixing code that not works is really something for StackOverflow, by all means come back after/if they fix your code for a codereview of your working code. Upvoted your question as a show of appreciation for your efforts.

Comment: Note the OP posted first on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555192/merge-sort-visualisation, but apparently did not quite understand the comments that were given there....

Comment: @keemahs, the question about the malfunctioning does not belong here, but on Stack Overflow. A question about optimisation could be on topic here, but only once you are certain the code works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code when changing the data size to a larger number, except that the `draw()` method doesn't adjust the width of the columns by the ratio between the canvas size and the number of columns to be drawn.

You'll have to do some math like:

```
  let offset = Math.round(canvaswidth / len);
  let rectWidth = Math.round(offset * 0.9);
```

The rounding is because you want integer values (pixels).

---

> ```
> ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
> ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500 - arr[i], 10, arr[i])
> if (seen[i]) {
>   ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"
>   ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500 - arr[i], 10, arr[i])
> }
> ```

This seems inefficient as you draw more and more columns twice through the sorting. A better solution would be something like:

```
ctx.fillStyle = seen[i] ? "#00ff00" : "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(offset * i, 500 - arr[i], rectWidth, arr[i]);
```

---

> ```
> for (let i = s; i <= e; i++) {
>     ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff"
>     ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500 - arr[i], 10, arr[i])
>     ctx.fillStyle = "#0000ff"
>     ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500, 10, arr[i])
>     seen[i] = 1
> }
> ```

You shouldn't "undraw" a column by drawing a white column over it. Instead you could use `clearRect` with the same dimensions.

---

> `let m = parseInt((s + e) / 2)`

You can integer divide by two by right shifting by one:

```
(s + e) >> 1
```

---

You should really be careful to end each statement with a ';' ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons))

---

> ```
> await merge(s, e)
> // await console.log(`merged ${s} to ${e} now draw...`)
> await draw(s, e)
> ```

You call these with `await` but they are not defined as `async`?

---

Your algorithm seems to works like a merge sort - as I recall it. I think I would encapsulate the parts into a class instead of having the functions in the global scope.

---

Besides that, I find you graphics very illustrative.

Comment: Note the text in the description: "_Now if i change the len variable in JS to above 50 i.e. 75 or 100 the code behaves oddly..why is it so?_" Questions involving code that's not working as intended, are off-topic. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.